# Joomla 3.4.1 Installation stuck at step 1

Tags: php, joomla, installation

I'm trying to install the latest Joomla 3.4.1 CMS on my webspace but I can't get past step 1 in the installation process. When I fill out the fields for the basic configuration and press the Continue-Button, a short Loading-Animation appears and immediately disappears again, with no change what so ever.

There are no PHP errors, no console errors, nothing that indicates a possible source of the problem. Trying out solutions that I found via Google that suggest commenting or changing lines in certain PHP files didn't help. I'm running PHP version 5.3.14. MagicQuotes are on (turning them off didn't help either).

Anyone ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Magic quotes need to be off. Try creating your database before starting the install.

Comment: Magic quotes are now off, no change so far. The database already exists, but I can't hook it up to Joomla (that would be in step 2, I'm stuck at step 1). When I add the database info to the configuration.php, the installer tells me that the installation is complete (wich it isn't of course because the database tables weren't even created yet).

Comment: How did you put the files in place? By FTP or by unzipping on your server?

Comment: Unzipped them locally, uploaded them via FTP. Even when I apply a 777 permission to all files, no change.

Comment: It's no about permissions, it is about ownership (probably).  Do you have cPanel or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you trying to install Joomla in HTTPS mode.
Switch to HTTP, install Joomla and then enable HTTPS mode again.

But the problem in your server settings. Check Apache modules. May be you need to add directive SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on.

Comment: "and then"... what?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem while installing Joomla 3.9.8 on PHP 7.2
Solved by adding

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

to the **php-bin/php.ini** file